# "IIS Admin Service is Disabled" Error When IIS Admin Is Running

Tags: iis, windows-xp, service, web-services

**Issue:**

I am trying to start the `Default Website` on IIS, but I am getting the following error:

[image: IIS Reset Issue]

As you can see, it says that IIS Admin is disabled, when it is actually running.

**Question:**

Is there any way to get IIS running?

Our VeryImportantWebsite™ has been down for a few days, and as a programmer, I'm not as IT inclined as I'd like to be.

Comment: How does it react if you try to start the "World Wide Web Publishing" service, from the services console? Any error messages?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I get `Could not start WWWP Service on Local Computer. Error 14: Not enough storage is available`. For what it's worth, there's 17GB free on the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the solution had to do with Active Directory.

The Domain Account we use for this machine because out of sync, and was using cached credentials. When we try to do an `iisreset`, the World Wide Web Publishing needs to start, but fails to start because of the mis-matched Domain credentials.

Re-syncing the Domain Account on the machine fixed the issue.